# Como comparar trechos de duas colunas de um DataFrame para gerar filtro

Tags: python, dataframe

Possuo um data frame com várias colunas. Preciso filtrar com base em duas, se o final da string de uma é igual ao da outra. p. exemplo:

```
Item 1           Item 2       Item 3
carro do joão    quitado     casa do joão
carro do josé    quitado     casa do antonio
carro do thiago  quitado     casa do thiago
```

Preciso pegar só as linhas em que os proprietários são os mesmos nos Item 1 e Item 3

Eu tentei dessa forma, mas ele só retorna uma lista [joao, joao], não consigo pensar em alternativas.

```
  teste = []

for row in dados.iterrows():
    teste += dados['Item 1'].str.split('do ')[1][1] == dados['Item 3'].str.split('do ')[1][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar um apply para separar a parte que você quer e aí comparar as duas séries.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item 1':['carro do joão', 'carro do josé', 'carro do thiago'],
              'Item 2':['quitado', 'quitado', 'quitado'],
              'Item 3':['carro do joão', 'carro do marcelo', 'carro do thiago']})
teste = df['Item 1'].str.split('do ').apply(lambda x: x[1]) == df['Item 3'].str.split('do ').apply(lambda x: x[1])
df[teste]
```

Ou usar .str.extract para pegar tudo que vier depois de um da/de/do/das/dos e comparar

```
teste = df['Item 1'].str.extract('.*d.+ (.*)', expand=False) == df['Item 3'].str.extract('.*d.+ (.*)', expand=False)
df[teste]
```

Answer (score -1):

Estou um pouco enferrujado mas e se for:

teste += dados[dados['Item 1'].str.split('do ')[1][1] == dados['Item 3'].str.split('do ')[1][1]] , funcionaria ?